# Could not write JSON: could not deserialize; nested exception is

Tags: json, spring, serialization, kotlin

Two models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
data class Product(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        var id: Long = 0,
        var name: String = "",
        var price: Number = 0
)

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
data class User(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Long = 0,
        var name: String = "",
        var email: String = "",
        @OneToMany(targetEntity = Product::class)
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
        var products: List<Product> = listOf()
) {
    var password: String = ""
        @JsonIgnore
        get() = field
}
```

My repository:

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    fun findByEmail(email: String): User
}
```

In my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
    fun index(): MutableIterable<User> = repository.findAll()
```

When I access http://localhost:8080/users I get the following error:

> Failed to write HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write JSON: could not deserialize; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not
>   deserialize (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0]->xxxxxxxxxxx.models.User["products"])

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`JpaRepository<User, Long>` instead `CrudRepository<User, Long>`

and

`List<User>` instead `MutableIterable<User>`